# Do we have $\{g x g^{-1}: x \in \mathfrak{g}\} = \mathfrak{g}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Fix $g \in G$. Do we have $\{gxg^{-1}: x \in \mathfrak{g}\} = \mathfrak{g}$? Thank you very much.

Edit: I think that the answer is yes. We have $\{gxg^{-1}: x \in \mathfrak{g}\} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ and for any $y \in \mathfrak{g}$, we have $y = g (g^{-1} y g) g^{-1} \in \{gxg^{-1}: x \in \mathfrak{g}\}$.

Comment: What does $gxg^{-1}$ mean when $g\in G$ and $x\in \mathfrak g$? Unless $G$ is a matrix group, you can't multiply an element of the group by an element of the Lie algebra. Probably you want to use the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation).

Comment: @Jack Lee, thank you very much. Yes, by $gxg^{-1}$ I mean $Ad_g(x)$. In general, do we have $\{Ad_g(x): x \in \mathfrak{g}\} = \mathfrak{g}$ for a given $g \in G$?

Comment: Yes. By definition $Ad_g(x)$ is always an element of $\mathfrak g$, and if $e$ is the identity of $G$, then $Ad_e(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Jack Lee, thank you very much.